# How to change a particle system's rotation without changing the direction in which emitted particles are heading?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Alright, so I have a 2d rocket with a particle system shooting squares and triangles as thrust. The issue I am having is that, the particles that are emitted rotate with the rocket when the rocket and the particle system turn. The particle system is a child to the rocket. So if the rocket is going up, the particles emit downwards, but say I turn the rocket to be going down, those already emitted particles change their position to be above the rocket and start going up. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it is just to change simulation space to world.

With mode set to local, any changes to your parent game object, or the particle system itself, propagates down to all the living particles.

With world, new particles will match the position and rotation of your rocket, but the ones already emitted will retain their direction, as local changes to transform of ps/any other parent, will no longer affect them.